# Custom JS loading twice

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom js file defined in a site def.  This gets injected into the master page head as expected.  However, something is also injecting another script tag into the body of the page and I cant find anywhere in my code that does this.  Does anyone know what this might be or how I can trace it?

Ive checked for CustomJSUrl controls and the script name in my source and it’s only mentioned in the master page once.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue - did you ever resolve this?  There is only one reference to the .js in the entire solution so I'm pretty sure I'm only specifying it in my onet.xml file.

Comment: Sorry, the SharePoint part of my brain has been replaced by something more interesting and less stressful.  I dont recall if we ever solved this.

Answer (score 0):

So you have it referenced in your site definition and in your master page? That makes 2..

Comment: Ah, yes, but the site def just registers the custom js url and the master page then references that, eg:

<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat=server />

or something like that..